# Determine function

Tags: functions

Let $f :\Bbb N \to\Bbb N$ be the function where $f(n)$ is the number of bits needed to express the positive integer $n$ (in decimal notation) in binary notation. Since $10$ (in decimal notation) is $1010_2$, then $f(10) = 4$.
(Take $\Bbb N$ to be the set of positive integers.)

a)Determine $f(31), f(32)$, and $f(33)$.
could u correct it if i'm right 
answer -    (31) = 00011111 = f(31)= 8
 (32)= 00100000= f(32)=8
 (33)= 00100001= f(33)= 8

Comment: Do you know how to express these numbers (31, 32, 33) in binary? Are you looking for a general form of the function? Some context will go a long way to helping users to give you a useful response.

Comment: no i do't know ;

Comment: Do you know *why* $1010_2$ is the binary form of $10_{10}$ in decimal? If not, we should direct you to a primer on binary.

Comment: do u mean f(31)10 = (00011111)2       f(31) =8

Comment: (31) = 00011111 = f(31)= 8
 (32)= 00100000= f(32)=8
 (33)= 00100001= f(33)= 8
is it correct?

Comment: I think you may need to omit the leading zeros, unless otherwise instructed. I would also recommend ensuring you understand the binary system, as this has been assumed in the exercise.

Comment: Please improve the question by removing the b) section, which is a completely different question, and posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to solve for $f(x)$ is the following:

1. Convert the argument (the number, $x$) from decimal to binary.
2. Count the number of digits.
3. Return the number of digits in decimal form.

How to convert to binary? An excellent primer is from [Math Is Fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-number-system.html). Below is a link to the graphic on their website.

[image: binary]

You can convert a number to binary through inspection using this graphic, and learn more about what you are doing by reading the [webpage](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-number-system.html).

If you want a quick and dirty conversion (without understanding what you are doing, however) see [this table](http://www.convertbinary.com/numbers.php). Reviewing that table may help you understand the pattern.

In the example given, look for the number $10$ in the left-hand column of the [table](http://www.convertbinary.com/numbers.php). You will find in the right-hand column the binary number $1010$. It has $4$ digits. Therefore $f(10)=4$.

Can you repeat this process for $f(31), f(32) \text{ and } f(33)$?

Comment: i did it but i were not sure because all have 8 digits

Comment: You don't have to convert the number to binary (although that is good practice).  You just need to find the highest power of 2 less than or equal to the number and add one.  31 is greater than 2^4 so it requires 5 bits (11111).  32 is 2^5 so it requires 6 (100000) and 33 is more than 265 so it also requires 6 (100001).

Comment: Good call, @fleablood!

Comment: The highest power of 2 is a "leading 1".  It doesn't matter how to convert the rest of the number as those are all "lower" bits and will take the same number of bits no matter how they are arranged.

Answer (score 0):

Um, the function is $[\log_2 n ]  $ where [x] the least integer greater than  to x.

Since $2^n$ in binary is 1000....0 (with n zeros) it takes $n + 1 = (\log_2 2^n) +1$ bits to represent it. $2^{n+1}$ in binary is 100....0 with n + 1 zeros and n+2 bits. If m is such $2^n < m < 2^{n+1}$ it will require n+1 bits to represent it.  As  $2^n < m < 2^{n+1}$ then $n < \log_2 n < n + 1$ so the bits to represent m would be [\log_2 m] = n + 1.

As $32 = 2^5$ it will take one 1 and 5 zeros to represent it.  So $f(32) = 6 = \log 32 + 1 = [\log 32]$.  31 will therefore take 5 bits.  $f(31) = 5 > \log 31 > 4$.  so $f(31) = [\log 31]$.  And so on.

Um, how can you know what binary *is* and not know how to express numbers in binary.

27  in binary, crash course:  Find highest power of 2 less than or equal to 27.  That is $2^4 = 16$.  Subtract from 27 to get $27 = 16 + 11 = 2^4 + 11$. Do the same for 11 to get $11 = 8 + 3 = 2^3 + 3$ so $27 = 2^4 + 2^3 + 3$.  Keep going to get $27 = 16 + 8 + 2 +1 = 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0$.  You mark each power of 2 with a 1 and you mark every missing power of 2 with a zero.  So $27 = 11011_2$.